# How can I close specific Excel files, when open, then export with VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to close a workbook:

```vb
Sub SaveWorkbook()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I need to export four Excel files from SAP and then it opens.

File names are always: "AA", "BB", "C" and "DD".

How can I close these specific Excel files when they are open?

Comment: Create a variable for it like `set wb1=workbooks("AA")`.

Comment: And then? What I need to change in code?

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Close` What do you think that does?

Comment: `For Each wb In Array("AA","BB","C","DD"): Workbooks(wb).Close(SaveChanges:=True): Next` should save and quit the specified files

Comment: Do the SAP-exported workbooks all open in the same instance of excel where you'll be running the code?

Comment: Yes @Tim! As excel files are exported to the folder, excel opens. I would like the code to close the files as they open. The files always have the same name. Is it possible to execute the code in the following way: when there is an excel file with the name "AA", the vba code closes?

Comment: This way is it correct?
    Sub close_workbook()

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("AA")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb1.Save
    wb1.Close
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub

Comment: If your macro workbook is already open before SAP exports the files, is there is difference in the output of `Debug.Print Application.Workbooks.Count` before vs. after the export?  That will tell you if a new instance is used for the exported files.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub close_workbook()

   Set wb1 = Workbooks("AA")

   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     wb1.Save
     wb1.Close
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```